# Zend multiparam URL to one parameter

Tags: php, url, zend-framework

Is there any solution to create this URL in Zend and get more URL parts as 1 parameter?

```
Ex.: /someApp/someFolder/Separator/Need/This/As/One/param/
```

and I need "Need/This/As/One/param" as 1 parameter...

My basic route is

```
"someApp/someFolder/Separator/:path/"
```

, I've tried something like

```
".../:path/*"
```

,... but nothing works ok. There will be no other param on the end of URL so it should be ok.

Comment: Do you want to have other parameters on the end of URL?

Comment: No, i did it as 10 single routes with 1, 2, 3, 4 ,... 10 params and then implode them in code to get 1 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It get string after `site/`. For example: `site/Need/This/As/One/param`. variable `path` will have string `Need/This/As/One/param`

```
'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => 'site/:path[/]'
        'defaults' => [...],
        'constraints' => [
            'path' => '.+',
        ]
    ]
]
```